# Retrieve first 10000 records from the database - grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a class called `News`. The properties of this domain class are shown below.

```
String name
String age
Chat chat
```

I have saved several records in the database for the above class. Now i want to retrieve the first 10000 records of it and display below.

```
    def news = News.createCriteria().list (max: 10000, offset: 5) {
        like("chat", Chat.get(chatId)+"%")
    }
```

All what i get is an error :

> //groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.project.mine.Chat.plus() is applicable for argument types:
>   (java.lang.String) values: [%]

Comment: How are you expecting a like on "chat" which is a Chat object to work? like is for text/string values. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to retrieve all `name` that has the same `chatID` (`chatID` is a property found in `Chat`). How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on further information in the comments, it would appear you are looking for a criteria something like this:

```
def news = News.createCriteria().list(max: 10000, offset: 5) {
  chat {
    eq("chatId", chatId) // assumes that chatId isn't the id of the Chat domain.
  }
}
```